# During a slideshow Excel does not activate

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

Hi I'm using office 2007 and I made a macro in ppt what opens xlsm files but during the slideshow if I start with the command button it opens the excel application and the file but does not activate it. 
Here is my code:

```
Dim appExcel as object
Const ExcelObject = "Excel.Application"
Set appExcel = CreateObject(ExcelObject)
appExcel.Visible = True
appExcel.File.Open:="path name"
appExcel.Workbooks("workbookname").Activate
```

So it goes on the activation without error and the slideshow still active not the excel file.

I tried to send alt+tab keys but still slideshow is active.
Is there any solution for my problem?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? why would you want an Excel file to show up in the middle of a PPT slide show?

Comment: becouse 20 users will use it and after they opened it excel have to do some user specific stuff and if macros aren't abeled in their pc tha open workbook events won't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim appExcel as object
Const ExcelObject = "Excel.Application"
Set appExcel = CreateObject(ExcelObject)
With appExcel
    .Visible = True
    .File.Open:="path name"
    .Workbooks("workbookname").Activate
    AppActivate .Caption '<<<<<<<
End With
```